# Image not showing on image slider

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, image

Hello im creating a dynamic image slider but the image is not showing. I can upload image in the file directory. I don't know what is the problem if the database is the problem or what. I'm new to html and css also to php. Can someone give me ideas what is the caused of not showing the images?

here it is the image is not showing but i can upload file to my gallery file directory.
[image]

here is my database sql.
[image]

here is my php code.

```
<?php
//for connecting db
include('connect.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}
else
{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$photo="gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];


$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO images(photo)VALUES('$photo')");
$result = $query; 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("image successfully uploaded ");window.location=\'index.php\';</script>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        controlsContainer: '.flexslider'
        });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <form class="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image">
            <p>Upload images and try your self </p>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
              <input type="submit" value="image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                    // Creating query to fetch images from database.
                   $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from images order by id desc limit 5");
                    $result = $query;
                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                ?>
                    <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $r['photo'];?>" width="400px" height="300px"/>
                    </li>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my connect.php

```
<?php
// hostname or ip of server
$servername='localhost';
// username and password to log onto db server
$dbusername='root';
$dbpassword='';
// name of database
$dbname='pegasus';

////////////// Do not  edit below/////////
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysql->connect_error);
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Image shows your column name is `image` and you are fetching records by column name `photo`? What's this?

Comment: hey man. how can i mark your comment as an answer? it worked.

Comment: hi sir i forgot to thankyou for referring the mysqli php manual before thanks :) i solved it myself.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help you

Comment: even tho i received so many minus votes hahahahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image shows your column name is image and you are fetching records by column name photo.

Just change

```
<img src="<?php echo $r['photo'];?>" width="400px" height="300px"/>
```

to

```
<img src="<?php echo $r['image'];?>" width="400px" height="300px"/>
```